# NHibernate one-to-many mapping

Tags: .net, nhibernate

I want to map one to many objects Person
and PersonAddress

```
public class Person{
public virtual int Id {get; set;} public virtual string FirstName {get; set;}
public virtual ICollection<PersonAddress> PersonAddress { get; set; }}

public class PersonAddress{
public virtual int Id {get; set;}
public virtual int PersonId {get; set;}
...     }
```

I don't want to have person object property in address. It creates cyclic references and don't necessary for my application.

mapping file is like following:

```
<class name="Person"  table="Persons" >
    <id name="Id" type="Int32" column="PersonId">
        <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <set name="PersonAddress" table="PersonAddress" lazy="true" fetch="join" outer-join="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
        <key column="PersonId"></key>
        <one-to-many class="PersonAddress"/>
    </set>  
</class>

<class name="PersonAddress"  table="PersonAddress" >
    <id name="Id" type="Int32" column="Id">
        <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="PersonId" column="PersonId" type="Int32"/>
    <property name="PhoneWork" column="PhoneWork" type="String"/>       
</class>
```

when trying to insert Person with person address I am receiving exception. Because it tries to insert PersonAddress with invalid id (default -1, 0, etc).

in samples that I have found it is specified back reference from child to parent

Comment: Sounds similar to a question I posted a while back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426767. Looks like you're out of luck but I have my fingers crossed for a satisfactory answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class Person {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<PersonAddress> PersonAddress { get; set; }
    ... }

public class PersonAddress {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    ... }
```

You should have a reference to the Person, and not just a PersonId.
And if you have difficulties with the .hbm.xml mapping files, consider using [Fluent NHibernate](http://fluentnhibernate.org/) instead. Its automatic mapping feature works like a charm.

There is also a [video series](http://www.summerofnhibernate.com/) on NHibernate, which covers the subject pretty well.

Comment: I know that it is possible by bidirection. But I was thinking about possibility without it. as I understand this is not possible.

Comment: I don't know if it is possible, but there is no point in doing it. Why is that Person property bothering you?

Answer (score -1):

Just answered [here](http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/ea5b1d2edbee18a9)

Comment: @EricHerlitz you know what's more productive than a downvote? Actually editing the answer.

Comment: Well, I will lift that dv whenever the post is updated. There are some links that are acceptable I.e. to MS documentation but referring to content in google groups are possibly comparable to technological genocide since it is the worst place on the planet when it comes to actually helping people and bringing clarity to information that is what SO is really good at instead. Update your own answer or the dv stays.

Comment: Eric, do you think I give a s*** about a downvote on a post I wrote more than 3 years ago? IIRC, the OP crossposted here and in the groups, and I answered there first. If you think you are making Stackoverflow better by being passive-aggressive, keep believing that.